# Using startactivityforresult with Flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start an activity B from activity A with intent set to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` now i want to get back some data from Activity B to Activity A, and for that i am using `startactivityforresult` now the problem happening is that, when i am calling `setresult` from Activity B then my activity A's `onactivityresult` is not getting called.

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening, and if it is not possible to use startactivityforresult with (NEW_TASK and CLEAR_TASK) then what can i try instead of this.

Also I am trying to use above two intents because i want to clear my back stack when i want to open activity B.

**In Activity A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("from", "A");
intent.putExtras(args);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
```

**On Activity B**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtras(data.getExtras());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Post the code from where you are setting and getting the data

Comment: @BrandonZamudio Please see my updated post.

Comment: @BrandonZamudio got anything ??

Comment: Are you well handling the onNewIntent method? and declared a launchMode in the manifest?

Comment: No i haven't declared any launch mode and why onnewintent, as setresult returns result in onactivityresult function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple :

the flag **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** , is Incompatible with **startActivityForResult()**.

So it wont work , any activity that is started by an Intent to which the flag "**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**" was added **can not** return a result.

Here is the part of Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) that specify this.

It says :

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
>   the activity being launched.

Comment: it is not mentioned in the docs, but if you do you this flag and asking for a result, you will immediately receive `RESULT_CANCELED` (at least in my case)